# Please can you give me advice about my project (multiple deported sensors and ADC with shielding, EMC, EMI ...)

Tags: circuit-design

I have a project consisting of making an ADC main board with a Raspberry PI4B which will allow me to measure differential voltages from an analog accelerometer sensor on remote micro-boards.

The fact I cannot use digital accelerometer is that I cannot synchronize them and so my vibration data will be delayed each with other. It is why I must use multiple analog source which will then be all acquire in a synchronized way.

I will use these vibration data to get frequency response for extracting modal frequency with specialized software (using OMA - Operation Modal Analysis). If my data are not synchronized the extraction will be biased.

My ADC have differential inputs so my idea is this but I don't know if it is correct? It multiply the number of GND and so perhaps it is a bad idea? (I have 32 sensors.)

Also, is it a problem that differential signals are not referenced by the GND in the main board?

But perhaps I need to connect GND to both ends in this case?

[image]

Else I can do that which is less expensive by taking power from main board. In this case there is only one GND so perhaps it is better?

[image]

What do you think is better?